# Is it possible to use another canvas element as a texture in three.js?

Tags: canvas, three.js

I want to add a canvas (not drawed in three.js) like texture for a three.js box.

Like an external canvas and use it like texture for a box's faces

Is it possible?

Comment: See the three.js docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See, for example, https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_canvas.html